# table view use customized cell file and how ot use segue

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I user Master-Detail created a project. On the `MasterViewController`, the table cell i use a `MasterCell.h` and `MasterCell.m` to build my customized cell, so my code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MasterCell *cell = (MasterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[MasterCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    NSString  *value = [[myContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.nameContentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];

    value = [[myContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Tele"];
    cell.teleContentLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];

    value = [[myContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"];
    cell.myImageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:value];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

And whan i want click the cell and push the `DetailViewController`, so my stroyboard is use the origin creat segue, but it didn't work, i think the segue is not my `MasterCell`, and i had try to change the storyboard cell custom Class, and it was't not success.How do I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your storyboard you should create segue not from cell, but from entire UITableViewController and set some identifier, for example "MySegue" and style is "Push".

Then in your tableViewController you should add

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
   }
```

and

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]){

    //do your stuff

    }
 }
```